# WPF Bind checkbox to bool?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox

I have a WPF checkbox binded to ViewModel nullable boolean property. I am setting this property to false or true in Constructor, to avoid Interminent state but no matter what I do the Initial state of checkbox stays grayed. The binding working just fine since once I change the state by clicking the checkbox on UI I am getting controls values (true/false). Any Ideas?

**XAML:**

```
<CheckBox Margin="0,4,0,3"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Content="Mutual"
          IsChecked="{Binding MutualChb}" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ContstrutorViewModel()
{
    MutualChb = true;
}

private bool? _mutualChb;
public bool? MutualChb
{
    get { return _mutualChb; }
    set
    { 
        _mutualChb = value; 
        _mutualChb = ( _mutualChb != null ) ? value : false;
        OnPropertyChanged("MutualChb");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine for me. Are you sure the binding is working? Have you set a breakpoint on the setter of `MutualChb` to see if it gets called when you click?

Comment: yes binding is working fine... I can get values once I click on UI on checkbox.. (true or false) depending on case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that is because it's initially null.

```
private bool? _mutualChb;
public bool? MutualChb
{
    get { return (_mutualChb != null ) ? _mutualChb : false; }
    set
    { 
        _mutualChb = value;               
        OnPropertyChanged("MutualChb"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `return (_mutualChb ?? false);` looks better

Comment: Yes @Jim i just went with your initial code but i would write (_mutualChb ?? false);